# Eclipse maven configuarion

Tags: eclipse, maven, config, m2e

I've recently changed the location of my maven repository from my C:\ drive to D:\ drive, however when I create a new eclipse workspace my m2e settings keep pointing back to the old repo location (C:) . Is there a master config file or something I can edit so when creating a new workspace it keeps the new repo location ?

Thanks.

Comment: how did you do this change?

Comment: Window->Preferences->Maven->User Settings

Comment: do you see a settings.xml file there?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I've changed the repo location . From C:\ to D:\ drive, and everytime I open a new workspace it still points to the repo on the C:\ drive.

Comment: you have to add this to the settings.xml. add this "<localRepository>D:\xxx\.m2\repository</localRepository>" to the file

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I should elaborate that I've moved the entire contents of the .m2 folder to my D: drive thats including the settings.xml. I have also added the <localRepository> tags to the file. The problem is that eclipse still references the C:\pathtomaven\settings.xml when loading a new workspace

Comment: First your settings.xml should be in your user home folder $HOME/.m2/settings.xml which is loaded by default. That's the one you should change to represent the change of your repository location...You can check this by running on console via `mvn -X clean` and within the first lines you see where maven is picking up the settings.xml from....Afterwards reimport your projects into Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse seems to create a .m2 folder under $HOME variable, which was set to a location on my C:\ drive. Was unable to set the $HOME to D:\ for other reasons, but using the

```
<localRepository>D:\local_maven\.m2\repository</localRepository>
```

tags I was able to change the repo location to my D:\ drive.